# Is there any way to reload multiple cron job Task Schedular

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, scheduler

So I have multiple cron jobs scheduled based on properties with Task Schedular, now I want to move those properties to DB. When any properties or job got update from UI , I will send DirectExchange flag to my application to reload all job once again.

```
  public void scheduleJobs() {
   list.forEach(task ->
            taskScheduler.schedule(mytaskMethods(task), new CronTrigger(task.getSchedular()))
    );
}
```

`here am stuck to reload task schedular to cancel running job and update new one, dont want to restart my application.`

Comment: I am using enable scheduling annotation and Task schedular to configure jobs in properties file, I can add multiple jobs if required , is there any way to reload cron jobs to task schedular